# How to calculate the integral $\int_0^\infty {\rm d}k\, k^{d-1} \frac{1}{\exp(\beta(E_k+\mu))+1}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How to calculate the integral $\int_0^\infty {\rm d}k\, k^{d-1} \frac{1}{\exp(\beta(E_k+\mu))+1}$? Here $E_k=\sqrt{a*k^2-b^2}$, and you can think $a, b, d, \mu$ is Real constant.

I don't now how to calculate it, and I use Wolfram Mathematica also can't get any useful information.

Comment: What's $\beta$ ?

Comment: Also a real constant.